# A proverb to state someone who likes neither the thing nor its opposite

Tags: slang, idiom-requests, colloquialisms, proverb-requests

Is there any particular expression, proverb, colloquial slang or the like to state a case when someone likes neither one thing nor its opposite?

Example 1:  *"I don't like cold weather because it's cold, but I don't like warm weather either because it's too warm."*

Example 2: *"I don't like when you don't let me decide what to do. If you do let me decide what to do, I don't like it either because I don't want to decide what to do."*

Comment: That's just human, the weather is never right ;)

Comment: Goldilocks. Her first bowl of porridge was too hot; the second was too cold. And so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These might have the flavor you're looking for.

From https://www.wiktionary.org/:

**damned if you do, damned if you don't**: (idiomatic) a dilemma where either choice results in a negative outcome.

**Catch-22**: (idiomatic) a difficult situation from which there is no escape because it involves mutually conflicting or dependent conditions.

**no-win situation**: any situation that is certain to end in failure or in which any favourable outcome is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

**Be in two minds** (about something) — [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-in-two-minds-about-something)

> to not be certain about something, or to have difficulty in making a decision
> *"I’m in two minds about accepting the job"*

**Undecided** — [Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/undecided)

> *adjective* 1. not decided or determined.
> 2. not having one's mind firmly made up.
>
> *noun* 3. a person who is undecided
> *"Are you still among the undecideds?"*

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find **negativist**, **naysayer**, or **contrarian** to be quite right.

How about **unpleasable**?

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unpleasable:

> **unpleasable**: not capable of being pleased or satisfied

Answer (score 0):

The situation ('case'?) is actually described in the Bible ('the like'?):

> We played the flute for you, but you didn't dance; we sang a lament,
>   but you didn't mourn!

[[Matthew 11:7; Holman Christian Standard Bible](http://biblehub.com/matthew/11-17.htm)]

I've seen a commentary describing some people who criticised a pastor who 'spent too much on a car', and then complained he was giving a shabby appearance when he swapped it for one a few hundred dollarmarks less.